# How to get records from table which has timestamp starting from particular date of previous month to particular date of this month in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a customer_visit table, my requirement is to get the records of previous month starting from 3rd date to current month 2nd date and which contains flag 'Y'. How can I achieve this in Postgres. Following is the sample of my table. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [make_date()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html) function from postgres to construct the date and query on it.

```
select * from customer_visit 
     where created_time > make_date(2018, date_part('month', now())::int - 1, 03)
     and created_time <= make_date(2018, date_part('month', now())::int, 02) 
     and flag = 'Y';
```

You can use date_part('year', timestamp) to extract year also from current date.